# How to pass a struct by value to a pthread?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

So I have a multithread C program in which will create *N* pthreads. I have to give the threads some arguments through a struct. In order to not have to allocate *N* structs, check if there was no malloc erros, pass them by reference to my threads and then free the struct array, I'd like to simply create a temporary struct and pass it by value. Here's a simple code that demonstrates the question:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct thread_arg {
    int value1;
    char value2;
    float value3;
};

void *foo(void *arg);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int N = atoi(argv[1]);
    pthread_t *thread = (pthread_t *) malloc(N * sizeof(pthread_t));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        struct thread_arg arg;
        arg.value1 = i;
        arg.value2 = 'f';
        arg.value3 = i / 10;
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, foo, arg);
    }

    free(thread);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *foo(void *arg)
{
    struct thread_arg my_arg = (struct thread_arg) arg;
    printf("%d%c%f\n", my_arg.value1, my_arg.value2, my_arg.value3);
    return NULL;
}
```

I know it's perfectly normal to pass a struct by value to a function that expects it, but with threads and its NULL pointers I get errors no matter what type of cast I make.

Comment: "you can't" is probably the answer

Comment: If the problem you are solving requires to create multiple threads then it is not a huge cost to malloc a struct and check if malloc failed.

Comment: Note that the code as posted is buggy, since it's possible (indeed likely) that by the time the foo() function executes in the child thread, the "arg" struct will no longer exist on the main thread's stack.  (The fix is, as others have said, to dynamically allocate the struct instead; that way the thread can control the struct's lifetime by freeing it when it is done using it)

Comment: do not reference beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameter actually exists.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to simply create a temporary struct and pass it [to a thread-start function] by value.

You can't.  Thread-start functions accept one argument of type `void *`.  You cannot convert the value of a struct to `void *` in any reasonable way.  You might be able to hack around the problem if the size of a `void *` were at least as large as the size of your struct's representation, but that does not appear to be the case for you.

Instead, I suggest creating an *automatic* array of as many structs as you need, and then passing each thread a pointer to its own one of those.  You can do that with a VLA even if you don't know before runtime how many you will need:

```
#define THREAD_LIMIT 50

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int N;

    if (argc < 2) {
        // handle too few arguments ...
        exit(1);
    }

    N = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (N < 0 || N > THREAD_LIMIT) {
        // handle invalid argument ...
        exit(1);
    } 

    struct thread_arg args[N];
    pthread_t threads[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        args[i].value1 = i;
        args[i].value2 = 'f';
        args[i].value3 = i / 10;

        if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, foo, &args[i])) {
            // handle thread creation failure ...
        }
    }

    // did you forget to pthread_join() your threads?
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Note that you can do the same thing for your array of `pthread_t`, as demonstrated above, and that releases you from the obligation to manually free memory.

If you want to be able to accommodate thread counts so large that the VLAs might exhaust the available stack space, or if you need this to work on a compiler that does not support C99 (e.g. MSVC++), then you can dynamically allocate the whole array of arg structs instead of allocating each struct individually, just as you do for your thread handles in your original code.

Whether you use a VLA or a dynamically allocated array or individual dynamically-allocated structs, it is of course necessary that the threads do not attempt to access the structs after the end of their lifetimes.  The lifetime of a VLA ends when control leaves the innermost block enclosing its declaration; in the above example that would be when the main thread exits.  The lifetime of a dynamically allocated object ends when it is freed, unless the program exits first.

If you intend for any of your threads to continue to run after the main thread exits, therefore, the VLA option is off the table, but dynamic allocation could still work if you never free the allocated memory, or if you are careful to orchestrate when it is freed.  On the other hand, you could as easily keep the main thread around as long as needed by making at join all its child threads before it exits, as I added to the example.

Do note, by the way, that these approaches do not consume any more memory than passing your structs by value would do, if it were possible to do that, because by definition, passing the structs by value would make copies of them.

Additional notes:

- Do check the program arguments, both number and value
- Do check the return values of your function calls, at least where they make a difference.  Thus, you should check `pthread_create()`, but perhaps you don't need to check `pthread_join()` in this case.
- If it does join all the child threads then the main thread can perform an ordinary return or `exit()` or reach-the-ending-}, instead of a `pthread_exit()`.

Comment: Using VLA is a very bad idea in general, and you have not addressed control of the lifetime at all. If the structs' lifetimes end before the threads finish using them, the program will have undefined behavior.

Comment: @R..: I think you're overly negative on VLAs.  There are comments about the joins missing.  And there should be an error check on N in the original code and in this answer (and each other answer that includes code at the moment) checking that N is neither zero nor negative nor too large for some indeterminate value of 'too large'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I wouldn't say "joins are missing". The fact that OP calls `pthread_exit()` from the main thread implies he's not interested in joining. `pthread_join()` is a *convenience* function -- by no means a necessity in pthreads. R..'s comments on VLA may be subjective (although I personally agree with them) but his comment on the lifetime not being addressed is valid.

Comment: Answer updated to address object lifetime, which applies whether VLAs or dynamic allocation is used.  As for joining the child threads, I acknowledge that it is not obligatory to do so in general, but in this case the OP does go to the trouble to keep track of all the thread IDs for no other apparent reason.  Having those in hand, one can easily perform the needed thread joins before the main thread exits, and it's mostly a question of style, preference, and different forms of convenience whether one should do so.

Comment: @usr: If he doesn't want to join the threads, they could (maybe should) be made detached threads. However, that's mostly immaterial — yes, you have to consider lifetime of the arguments passed to the `pthread_create()` function and you certainly can't pass structures by value to `pthread_create()` unless the structure is small enough to fit into a `void *` (not very big!) and you're prepared to go through casting gymnastics that are basically unnecessary. If you try to fight the system, expect the system to fight back — and `pthread_create()` (the relevant bit of the system) expects pointers.

Comment: This is wrong. I passed a struct pointer to `pthread_create()` successfully in a server application. `struct client *client = malloc(sizeof(struct client));` and `pthread_create(& (threads[n].id), NULL, (void*)chatwrapper, client);`

Comment: What does that have to do with the question or this answer, @Ryan?  The OP wants to pass a struct to the thread start function ***by value***.  That one can pass struct *pointers* is true, but not germane.  Furthermore, this answer already discusses dynamically allocating memory for the struct data and passing pointers to that.  So what exactly is it that you claim is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

It's true that a struct value can be passed to a function by value. But `pthread_create()` expects a *pointer* as the argument (which will be passed to the thread function). So it's not possible to pass by value.

I suggest `malloc`'ing N struct values and pass a separate pointer to each thread and you could free each of them from the thread function itself:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int N = atoi(argv[1]);
    pthread_t *thread = malloc(N * sizeof(pthread_t));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        struct thread_arg arg;
        arg.value1 = i;
        arg.value2 = 'f';
        arg.value3 = i / 10.0;
        struct thread_arg *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
        *p = arg;
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, foo, p);
    }

    free(thread);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *foo(void *arg)
{
    struct thread_arg my_arg = *(struct thread_arg*) arg;
    printf("%d%c%f\n", my_arg.value1, my_arg.value2, my_arg.value3);
    free(arg);
    return NULL;
}
```

I left out error checking for brevity. But you should always check the return value of `malloc()` for failure.

Also, note that the statement has integer division (`i/10`):

```
arg.value3 = i / 10;
```

which may not be what you wanted. You can fix with:

```
arg.value3 = i / 10.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

As usr wrote, you cannot pass structs to a thread start function by value because `pthread_create`'s interface doesn't facilitate doing that. Usually the least expensive (in terms of logic complexity and performance) solution is to use `malloc` and have the start function `free` the struct once it's no longer needed, but if there is some reason you really don't want to use `malloc`, you can put a `sem_t` semaphore inside the struct, have the thread start function `sem_post` it after it's finished reading from it, and have the thread that calls `pthread_create` do `sem_wait`. Then the "parent" thread controls the lifetime of the struct, so it can safely have automatic storage ("on the stack") in the parent thread.

Answer (score 1):

Many before me wrote the obvious answer, you can't...

...**However**... There is a **limited** way in which **it is possible**.

If the whole of your struct fits within `sizeof(void *)`, you can pass that information by value rather then by reference.

On some systems, mostly embedded and legacy systems, `sizeof(void *)` can be quite small (i.e. 16 bits). On recent systems, you can get quite a lot of information in there (most recent systems use 64 bits).

In this example I will use 32 bits to in the struct (I will also use a `union` instead, most for convenience):

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdint.h"
#include "pthread.h"

#if !defined(UINTPTR_MAX) || UINTPTR_MAX < UINT32_MAX
#error Not enough space in a pointer for what we need or missing information.
#endif

union thread_arg {
  void *to_arg;
  struct {
    uint16_t value1;
    uint8_t value2;
    uint8_t value3;
  } data;
};

void *foo(void *arg);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2)
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Provide N\n\n"), exit(1);
  int N = atoi(argv[1]);
  if (N < 0 || N > UINT16_MAX)
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: N should be 0-%u\n\n", UINT16_MAX), exit(1);

  pthread_t *thread = malloc(N * sizeof(pthread_t));

  union thread_arg thread_arg;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    thread_arg.data.value1 = (uint16_t)i;
    thread_arg.data.value2 = 'f';
    thread_arg.data.value3 = (uint16_t)i; // whatever...?
    if (pthread_create(thread + i, NULL, foo, thread_arg.to_arg))
      fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't initiate thread no. %i\n", N), exit(1);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);

  free(thread);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *foo(void *arg) {
  union thread_arg thread_arg = {.to_arg = arg};
  printf("%d%c%f\n", thread_arg.data.value1, thread_arg.data.value2,
         (float)thread_arg.data.value3 / 10);
  return NULL;
}
```

Good lock!

Comment: Down-voted because...? Really, people, if you don't explain a down-vote, how is one to learn?

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting hack around. Thanks for demonstrating how to do it.

Comment: @FredericoOliveira, You're very welcome, this is what we're all here for. Usually we don't thank each other on SO, we simple up vote and accept good answers that helped us - otherwise, we'd fill up the site with thank you notes :)